# google maps → fitBounds manually

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently stuck with google maps v3.
I try to add bounds manually in this way, but it doesn't work!?

`map.fitBounds((53.399999, 9.73215099999993), (53.717145, 10.123491999999942));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`fitBounds`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) expects an object of the type [`LatLngBounds`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds), which in turn is initialized with two [`LatLng`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng) objects.

This should work:

```
sw = new LatLng(53.399999, 9.73215099999993);
ne = new LatLng(53.717145, 10.123491999999942);
bounds = new LatLngBounds(sw, ne)

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Reference:

- [V3 API Reference on `LatLng`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng)
- [V3 API Reference on `LatLngBounds`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds)
- [V3 API Reference on `fitBounds()`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map)