# Google maps API V3 fitBounds() not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm want to call `fitBounds()` on a google map so that a user can see their own location relative to a selected marker/location.

Here is my function which handles this:

```
var fitMapToShowResult = function(index){
    var hereLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng (lat,lng); //location of the user defined outside this func
    var firstResultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                                $scope.searchResults[index].geometry.location.k,
                                $scope.searchResults[0].geometry.location.B
    );
    var latlngList = new Array( hereLatLng, firstResultLatLng ); // latlng: an array of instances of GLatLng
    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i=0;i<latlngList.length;i++){
       latlngbounds.extend(latlngList[i]);
       console.log('latlngbounds',latlngbounds);
    }
    //$scope.map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
    $scope.map.fitBounds(latlngbounds); 

};
```

It works perfectly about 80% of the time. But roughly 1 in 5 times the marker is completely out of view and the zoom is way too high for the two points to ever be visible at the same time. What am I doing wrong?

It may be relevant that my map uses custom markers.

To assist with debugging, I added this code to draw the bounds on the map...

```
    rect = new google.maps.Rectangle( {bounds: latlngbounds, map: $scope.map} );
```

It always looks perfect for the first couple results:
[image]

But often it's incorrect:
[image]
[image]
Notice that in each of the cases where it's incorrect, it appears that one of the dimensions of the rectangle (height/width) is correct, but the other is not. My gut tells me this is relevant.

### Roundup of similar questions

I know this is a popular question, but I've reviewed all of the others and my issue does not seem to be a duplicate of any of them. Hopefully this stockpile will be useful to future troubleshooters, but none of these solved my issue.

[google maps V3 fitBounds not accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570721/google-maps-v3-fitbounds-not-accurate)
Useless question with no code and no answers

[Google Maps API v3 - fitBounds centers only one marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264762/google-maps-api-v3-fitbounds-centers-only-one-marker)
User was re-defining the inside a loop without realizing it.

[Using setZoom() after using fitBounds() with Google Maps API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523023/using-setzoom-after-using-fitbounds-with-google-maps-api-v3) & 
[Google Maps API V3 fitbounds() zooms out but never in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251774/google-maps-api-v3-fitbounds-zooms-out-but-never-in) & 
[Google Maps with fitBounds don't zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565539/google-maps-with-fitbounds-dont-zoom)
fitBounds() happens asyncronously so downstream actions need to be wrapped in eventListener.

[google maps → fitBounds manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421196/google-maps-%E2%86%92-fitbounds-manually)
User was passing incorrect type parameters to `LatLngBounds` (should be two `google.maps.LatLng`s)

[google maps fitBounds() is broken or..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640356/google-maps-fitbounds-is-broken-or) & [Google maps API V3 method fitBounds()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268033/google-maps-api-v3-method-fitbounds)
Was constructing the `google.maps.LatLngBounds` with buggy coordinates (instead of leaving it empty and using `.extend()`)

[Trying to get Google Maps fitbounds to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061273/trying-to-get-google-maps-fitbounds-to-work)
Super noob did not realize javascript methods were case sensitive

[Google maps V3 custom marker images and fitBounds()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676140/google-maps-v3-custom-marker-images-and-fitbounds)
`fitBounds()` works as expected but user needed to allow more space for bug custom markers

[Google Maps V3 fitBounds on visible markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299113/google-maps-v3-fitbounds-on-visible-markers)
Simple question about how to use `fitBounds()`... rtfm

[Google Maps API V3 - fitBounds randomly works but occasionally ignores bounds and loads in the middle of the ocean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013015/google-maps-api-v3-fitbounds-randomly-works-but-occasionally-ignores-bounds-an)
No answers at time of writing. Sounds like invalid lat/lng pairs.

Comment: Why are you calling both `$scope.map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());` and `$scope.map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);`?  They may be interfering with each other.

Comment: @geocodezip Sorry that was a mistake. I experimented with both. It doesn't seem to matter if the setCenter() is included or not, so I've removed it.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue?

Comment: You should avoid `geometry.location.k`. As stated above, please provide a MCVE so that we know what is `$scope.searchResults` and other variables as well.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Where is the remark about `geometry.location.k` that you are referencing? I'd like to understand that better. I'm working on a MCVE but it's taking some time because I have to carve this bug out of a large javascript app for it to be "M"

Comment: Where you are using `$scope.searchResults[index].geometry.location.k` and `$scope.searchResults[0].geometry.location.B`. `geometry.location` is not a plain object. It is a `LatLng` object. Therefore you should use the `lat()` and `lng()` methods because properties `k` and `B` are subject to change.

Comment: nice roundup of the similar questions! Great place to look for common mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MrUpsidown was right. My bounding box was wrong because I was referencing `....geometry.location.k` directly instead of the `LatLng` object. Refactoring the code accordingly corrected the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the values as `geometry.location.**k**`, it depends on minimized file (with some tool like MinifyJS) then it'll changes when google release a new versión.